# Conditional statement in express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im using Node and Express for a API REST. Is it possible to add a condition IF statemtent in the router? Just like this:

```
.route('/app')
    .post(
          openPool
        , checkToken
        , checkCondition //set req.condition = true
        (req, res, next) => {
              if (req.condition === true){
                Controller1
              , Controller2
              }
              next()
        }
        , sendResponse
);
```

It doesnt throw any error, it just doesnt execute the code of Controller1 and Controller2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If controllers are functions you should do something like this:

```
Controller1(req, res, () => Controller2(req, res, next))`
```